# insert value in new column from another column based on criteria from other column

Tags: python, pandas

```
   ColA                      ColB
0   Vendor account :         TX-8888881
1   Invoice account :        sdfhsa
2   NaN                      NaN
3   2020-11-01 00:00:00      NaN
4   Vendor account :         TX-8888885
```

I have 2 columns like above I want to create a new column which have value from column 'ColB' if there is value 'Vendor account :' in 'ColA' otherwise Nan.

The required table would be like below.

```
   ColA                      ColB            VendorAccount
0   Vendor account :         TX-8888881      TX-8888881
1   Invoice account :        sdfhsa
2   NaN                      NaN
3   2020-11-01 00:00:00      NaN
4   Vendor account :         TX-8888885      TX-8888885
```

I am using the code
`df['VendorAcount']= np.where(df['ColA'] == 'Vendor account :' , df['ColB'] , np.nan)`

Comment: Your solution is super, not working?

Comment: yes not working

Comment: `df['VendorAcount']= np.where(df['ColA'].astype(str) == 'Vendor account :' , df['ColB'] , np.nan)`.  Just add .astype(str)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need test substrings by [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df['VendorAcount']= np.where(df['ColA'].str.contains('Vendor account'), df['ColB'], np.nan)
```

Or start of strings by [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

```
df['VendorAcount']= np.where(df['ColA'].str.startswith('Vendor account'),df['ColB'], np.nan)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try and convert the value to `.astype(str)`

```
df['VendorAcount']= np.where(df['ColA'].astype(str) == 'Vendor account :' , df['ColB'] , np.nan)
```